# how to prevent the related list records from Edit and Delete function?

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule

I have object called Carset.In Carset am having a field "Valid" checkbox.

If the checkbox is checked then i cannot edit or delete the related list record(Child object-Service)

for editing i have written the below validation rule.It's working.

```
  IF(Car_Set__r.valid__c,true,false)
```

But for delete how to handle it using validation rule ?

Comment: you need to handle delete case using trigger

Comment: without using trigger we can't handle ?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008qy2IAA here answer is choosen .am not able to get it

Comment: uma that's only for update case. since validation rule doesn't fire on delete of record. You need to go with a simple trigger approach to prevent deletion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since validation rule doesn't fire on delete of record. You need to go with a simple trigger approach to prevent deletion

```
trigger triggerName on CustomObject__c (before delete)
{
   for(CustomObject__c obj: Trigger.old)
   {
     if(obj.valid__c) 
     {
        obj.addError('You can not delete this record');
     }
   }
}
```